# What's the Big-O-notation for this algorithm for printing the prime numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, big-o, primes

I am trying to figure out the time complexity of the below problem.

```
import math
def prime(n):
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
            if i%j == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(i)

prime(36)
```

This problem prints the prime numbers until 36.

My understanding of the above program:
for every n the inner loop runs for sqrt(n) times so on until n.

so the Big-o-Notation is O(n sqrt(n)).

Does my understanding is right? Please correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: The outer loop runs n times, the inner loop runs between 1 and sqrt(i) times. So the analysis is a little tricky. 1/2 of the time the inner loop runs only once, for even numbers. 1/3 of the time it runs only twice,  and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity measures the increase in number or steps (basic operations) as the input scales up:

```
O(1)     : constant (hash look-up)
O(log n) : logarithmic in base 2 (binary search)
O(n)     : linear (search for an element in unsorted list)
O(n^2)   : quadratic (bubble sort)
```

To determine the *exact* complexity of an algorithm requires a lot of math and algorithms knowledge. You can find a detailed description of them here: [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20the%20time,takes%20to%20run%20an%20algorithm.&text=Thus%2C%20the%20amount%20of%20time,related%20by%20a%20constant%20factor.)

Also keep in mind that these values are considered for very large values of n, so as a rule of thumb, whenever you see nested for loops, think O(n^2).

You can add a `steps` counter inside your inner for loop and record its value for different values of n, then print the relation in a graph. Then you can compare your graph with the graphs of `n`, `log n`, `n * sqrt(n)` and `n^2` to determine exactly where your algorithm is placed.